# ¿Cómo usar parámetros en aplicación en C# de consola?

Tags: c#, consola, parámetros

Buen día compañeros, soy nuevo en programación, necesito que me ayuden pros.
verán, estoy escribiendo una aplicación en C# que es para consola, la app sirve para editar la variante de entorno path de windows, por lo que necesito utilizar parámetros por ejemplo:

pat c:\users\yo\apps

donde pat es la app y el parámetro es el directorio, entonces la app cambiará la variante path por mi direción.

Gracias

estoy usando la variante temporal xvar, para no hacer cambios al la variante de entorno %Path% ya que un valor erróneo de la misma imposibilitará la ejecucuón adecuada del systema, pero una vez listo para compilar xvar se reemplazará por Path.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

{

```
    if (args.Length == 0)
{ Console.WriteLine(" -- syntáxis incorrecta introduce un parámetro"); Environment.Exit(1);
}
if (args.Length > 2)
{ Console.WriteLine(" -- syntáxis incorrecta introduce un parámetro y una dirección"); Environment.Exit(1); }

if (args.Length == 1)
{ Console.WriteLine(" -- syntáxis incorrecta introduce un parámetro y una dirección"); Environment.Exit(1); }

string job = args[0];
string dir = args[1];




{ // Condicional de parámetros
    if (args[0] == "-a" || args[0] == "-d" || args[0] == "-s")

    { //env path get
        VarSetX.VarSet(args);
        string path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("xvar");
        string variableValue = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(path); string xvar = "path";
        using var envKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment", true);
        Contract.Assert(envKey != null, @"registry key is missing!"); string pathx = path + ";";



        //job add
        if (job == "-a")

        {
            envKey.SetValue("xvar", path + ";" + dir);
            SendNotifyMessage((IntPtr)HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE,
                (UIntPtr)0, "Environment"); Console.WriteLine(" -- Operación exitosa: > '" + dir + "' se añadió al path");
            //job subs
        }

        if (job == "-d")
        {
            string pathn = path.Replace(";" + dir, string.Empty);
            Console.WriteLine("echo 0");
            // Console.WriteLine(pathn);
            envKey.SetValue("xvar", pathn);
            SendNotifyMessage((IntPtr)HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE,
                (UIntPtr)0, "Environment"); Console.WriteLine(" -- Operación exitosa: > '" + dir + "' se removió del path");
        }

    }

    //job set
    else
        if (args[0] == "-s")
    {
        string path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("xvar");
        using var envKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment", true);
        Console.WriteLine("Set");
        envKey.SetValue("xvar", dir);
        SendNotifyMessage((IntPtr)HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE,
            (UIntPtr)0, "Environment"); Console.WriteLine(" -- Operación exitosa: > ' el nuevo path es: " + dir);
    }
    else Console.WriteLine(" -- No Mames introduce un parámetro (-a para añadir, -d para eliminar, -s para sobreescribir)");
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! sabes que eso esta en la documentacion, no?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: es un poco ambigua tu pregunta, quieres guía de como usar archivo de configuración o como usar el parametro args de Main o algo así?

Comment: si el parámetro args, por favor,

Comment: Pon tu código, lo que intentas y veremos cómo poder ayudarte

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: El parámetro `args` no es nada más que un arreglo de cadenas. No veo cuál es la duda en eso. A menos que estés buscando librerías para controlar mejor los parámetros https://stackoverflow.com/q/491595/13419694